# Removing ? and & from URLS

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

So currently I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index\.php)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

and it works perfectly if I use for example: localhost/?login -> localhost/login

But I decided I wanted to fix this for my forum which uses localhost/?forum&id=123 and make it look like localhost/forum/123

And I'm not too sure how to fix this, tried for a few hours now.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for but it could be `qsappend` as described under http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Why would you want to remove query string from the URI without doing something with those values?

Comment: Edited the post, basically I want to make it say localhost/forum/123 instead of localhost/?forum&id=123. I have localhost/forum working though. Need help adding so I can do the same with the id.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve something similar the other day and this is what I ended up having in my .htaccess file that worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^forum/(.+)\.php /forum?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that I'm not a pro of regex, so in your specific situation this may not work. I myself had to fiddle around it for a while until I got it working.

My URL looked like this: `/forum?id=012` and it got transformed into `/forum/012` and in my php call I had `include('/forum/012.php');` on `if ($_GET['id'] == '012')` (this was in a loop, but this is basically the jist of the php side of things).

Answer (score 0):

The following should change `localhost/?forum&id=123` to  `localhost/forum/123`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?forum=(.*)&id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3\? [R,L]
```